# Converts scss to css

Tags: css, sass

Does anyone know how can I convert this code to standard css?
It's not working in their editor.

http://codepen.io/andymcfee/pen/eyahr

Comment: https://sass2css.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you click on the title `CSS (SCSS)` in CodePen (don't change the pre-processor with the gear) it will switch to the compiled CSS view.

[image: Codepen Screenshot of Compiled Preview]

Comment: There's now an eye icon on the right that does the job.

Comment: You know have to click the 'View Compiled' button near the top of the CSS tab.

Comment: At the time of writing there is a "caret" at the right hand corner of the css tab which does the job. a dropdown will appear from there select "view compiled CSS".

Comment: In 2020, you can click down-arrow icon to the top right corner of css panel, open a drop-down menu, choose, 'view compiled css'.    You can toggle back by choose 'view uncompiled css'

Answer (score 90):

In terminal run this command in the folder where the systlesheets are:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Source:

http://sass-lang.com/

When ever it notices a change in the `.scss` file it will update your `.css`

This only works when your `.scss` is on your local machine. Try copying the code to a file and running it locally.

Comment: I'm on Windows7. Where do I find the terminal? Isn't it a Linux thing? As you can see I know nothing about sass and terminals.

Comment: Use the cmd, click run then cmd. follow the instructions on there website about setting scss up. You can then save the file you want on your machine and turn it into a .css

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I was hoping for something like an online converter. This is probably the only time I will ever use sass so I'm not really looking to install stuff. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Sass Error: Undefined mixin 'backface-visibility' and Sass Error: Inconsistent indentation: 5 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces. Strange they are the same errors I got from here http://cssconvert.mgwebsolutions.net/

Comment: Ok. My best bet would be to look at this, ohttps://www.google.co.uk/search?q=online+scss+compiler&oq=online+scss+compiler&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2.467&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 there seems to be a few converts you have to download though. Best of luck.

Comment: Codepen seems to converting it, so why not just grab the compiled css from the developers console in your browser?

Answer (score 11):

**This is an online/offline solution and very easy to convert.**
[SCSS to CSS converter](https://sass2css.herokuapp.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you have to install Ruby if it is not on your machine.

1.Open a terminal window.
2.Run the command which ruby.

If you see a path such as `/usr/bin/ruby`, Ruby is installed. If you don't see any response or get an error message, Ruby is not installed. 
To verify that you have a current version of Ruby, 
run the command `ruby -v`.

If ruby is not installed on your machine then

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0-dev
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/bin/gem2.0 1
```

After then install Sass gem by running this command

```
sudo gem install sass --no-user-install
```

Then copy or add any .sass file and go to that file path and then

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

When ever it notices a change in the .scss file it will update your .css

This only works when your .scss is on your local machine. Try copying the code to a file and running it locally.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sass /sassFile.scss /cssFile.css`

> Attention: Before using `sass` command you must install ruby and then install sass.
>
> For installing sass, after ruby installation type `gem install sass` in your *Terminal*
>
> Hint: sass compile `SCSS` files

Answer (score 1):

**Install Ruby-sass using below command** 
sudo apt-get -y update 
sudo apt-get -y install ruby-full
sudo apt install ruby-sass
gem install bundler

**Example**
sass SCSS_FILE_PATH:CSS_FILE_PATH;

e.g sass mda/at-md-black.scss:css/at-md-black.css;