# OptionParser::MissingArgument: missing argument: --style + SASS

Tags: css, sass

When I am trying to convert my scss file to css using following command -

`sass --watch ex1.scss:ex1.css --style`

I am getting following error -

```
OptionParser::MissingArgument: missing argument: --style
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I followed this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649505/4818458

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Any reason for downvote or its in your blood to presume that the concept you know is equally known to others ?

Comment: Running `sass --help` would have given you your answer.  I've edited the other answer.  It may have been allowed to run the command like that in an older version, but it isn't now.

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **@cimmanon**, I am able to figured out the generation of css from scss files -

Command -

```
sass --update ex1.scss:ex1.css
```