# importing bourbon CSS extension when loading local files into browser

Tags: css

I am trying to run a customized HTML5 slider control from https://codepen.io/gabrieltomescu/pen/GsbIi on my PC (no webserver installed, just opening HTML and CSS files from local folder).

At the beginning of the CSS there is an import statement
`@import "bourbon";`

From what I gather, bourbon is an Sass extension (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon).

Is there any way I can download a bourbon package that will import into the CSS file if I am running the CSS from a local folder on my PC (not via a webserver)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CSS tab, by clicking the down arrow on the title bar(not the gear icon), you can view the compiled CSS (from scss) in codepen. you can copy the compiled source from there
for more details

[Converts scss to css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649471/converts-scss-to-css)